# No code highlights in fx:Script of flash builder 4.5

Tags: actionscript, flex4, syntax-highlighting

It seems all codes inside fx:Script blocks are black with no highlights. That's pretty inconvenient. Can anyone please let me know how to turn it on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I was using two different namespaces in Application and Module. It's "adobe.com/2006/mxml"; in mx:Application and "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" in mx:Module. After the namespace in mx:Application was made consistent with the one from mx:Module, all syntax are highlighted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First check that the active perspective is "Flash".
Then Window->Preferences. On the left side of the window expand Flash Builder->Editors->Syntax Coloring. On the right side you can set the colors for ActionsScript, CSS and MXML.

If after tinkering around you cannot fix the problem try to delete the "Adobe Flash Builder 4.5" folder located in the user's folder.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks a lot for the reply. What user's folder do you mean? Is it the installation folder of FB 4.5? By the way, the first two methods didn't work.

Comment: In Windows 7 is c:\users\YourUsername;  In Windows XP is c:\documents and settings\YourUsername

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. However, I think I've found the cause. I was using two different namespaces in Application and Module. It's "http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" in mx:Application and "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" in mx:Module. After the namespace in mx:Application was made consistent with the one from mx:Module, all syntax are highlighted correctly. Thanks for the help!